# deploy development and master branch on server with git

Tags: git, django

I´m using `git` for a `django` webproject. I have a bare git repo on my server and push my commits from my local machine into it. I also have a testserver on my local machine but I would like to have 2 versions of the website on the server. one version as live site (master branch) and one version as testserver (develop branch). So I need 2 working directories.

I would like to use the `post-receive` hook to

1. update my master branch working directory (for the live site on server)
2. update my develop branch working directory (for my test site on server)

normally I would do

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

but GIT_WORK_TREE seems not to be the right choice here I guess? Is there a better way?

how can I define the working directories for branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [article at digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) instead of GIT_WORK_TREE you need a combo of --work-tree and --git-dir options:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=/home/demo/proj checkout -f
```

and for post-receive script it ends up being slightly different construct than what you have:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=/home/demo/proj checkout -f
    fi
done
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "*** Moving to Live ***"
echo

cd /path/to/project || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

echo
echo "*** Pulling to Live ***"
echo                                               

/etc/init.d/nginx restart
#exec git-update-server-info
```

Took from my server and works well for me.

Don't forget to fix the path, the remote and the restart command.